# What is static complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, kolmogorov-complexity

**Definition :** Kolmogorov complexity is a static complexity measure that captures the difficulty of describing a string.

For example, the string consisting of three million zeroes can be described with fewer than three million symbols (as in this sentence)

From wikipedia

> In algorithmic information theory (a subfield of computer science and mathematics), the Kolmogorov complexity of an object, such as a piece of text, is the length of the shortest computer program (in a predetermined programming language) that produces the object as output. It is a measure of the computational resources needed to specify the object, and is also known as descriptive complexity, Kolmogorov–Chaitin complexity, algorithmic entropy, or program-size complexity

I am not able to understand few things like " static complexity " and why we need it

Comment: You can find a formal definition on "Classical recursion theory" Chapter VII.1, in the context of recursion theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complexities in this context could be divided into dynamic and static:

- **Dynamic complexity** is an attribute of the execution of a program with the string as an input. For example, the time or space complexity of a Turing machine to accept or reject a string.
- **Static complexity** is an attribute of a program that receives the string as input but not its execution. As you stated, Kolmogorov complexity is a static complexity since it is the length of the shortest program that creates the given string, an attribute that implies nothing about the execution of the program.

Comment: _"Algorithms and Theory of Computation Handbook, Second Edition, Volume 1"_, chapter 24 page 21.  IMHO it is not a formal definition since it is not stated explicitly anywhere on the internet, I understood it from the context of where the quote was taken from.